# UIView Resize for content

Tags: ios, autolayout

Couldn't find any answer for this, or am I missing something...

In iOS with autolayout on storyboard. If I have a UIView with some controls in it, depending on what the user clicks, the subviews are resizing. Can I somehow have the superview resize to the content?

In my app I have a view, but if a button is clicked subview is hidden I want the superviews height to decrease to exclude the hidden view. I can hook up the height constraint and handle it programatically, but it would be nice to handle it automatically....

Is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

Can I assume that you have some constraint that relates the size of your superview to the size of your subview?

If so, all you will need to do to resize your superview when you hide the subview, is change the height constraint of your subview to 0 (auto layout won't care if your subview is hidden or not, it only takes into account constraints).

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this:

You can try putting this code to your `buttonAction`

```
yourView.frame = CGRect(x: anotherView.bounds.minX, y: anotherView.bounds.min, width: anotherView.bounds.width , height: anotherView.bounds.height)
```

in this case "yourView" will change its size to "anotherView".

```
yourView.frame = CGRect(x: anotherView.bounds.minX, y: anotherView.bounds.min, width: anotherView.bounds.width , height: anotherView.bounds.height / 2)
```

This example will change the height to 1/2 of "anotherView" frame.

Hope it will help you a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

I was missing something..

What I didn't get was that the view will resize for its contents if you don't set a height for it and have the content have a constraint for the bottom of the view.

So I ended up setting the height of the hidden control to 0, and the bottom control constraint to parent bottom.